# facebook application using flex

Tags: flash, flex3, swc

how to develop new facebook application (login , add photos ) using the api of flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/articles/first_flex_facebook_web_app_pt1.html